# FullCalendar does not unselect previous selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I've been working with FullCalendar lately for a reservation system.
The problem is that whenever I select a time range it all adds to the eventData object. What I am trying to do is select one time range only.

When I click the `$('#btn-reserve')` button it should render the event on the calendar.

What's happening is that even my previous selections are getting rendered on the calendar. I only want to render the last selection I made.

here is my code

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar({
    selectable: true,
    select: function(start, end) {
            $('#end_time').val(end);
            $('#start_time').val(start);
            $('#newScheduleModal').modal({
                show : true,
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
            });

            $('#btn-reserve').click(function(){
                    eventData = {
                        title: 'Lesson Schedule',
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                    $('#newScheduleModal').modal('hide');
            });

            $('#btn-cancel-reserve').click(function(){
                $('.calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                eventData = {};
            })
    },

})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a new click event every time the calendar is selected.  You need to unbind the click before adding it like so:

```
 $('#btn-reserve').off('click').click(function
```

You might want to do the same for your "#btn-cancel-reserve" element.